# Comparing 2 Dictionaries where the values are Lists but have the same keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, comparison

I have the following dictionaries:

```
dict1 = 
{0: [48844000000, 51713000000, 22926000000, 4106000000, 22878000000, 12352000000, 162819000000], 
 1: [105341000000, 37378000000, 32978000000, 175697000000, 338516000000], 
 2: [46236000000, 37720000000, 5522000000, 6000000000, 5980000000, 10260000000, 105718000000], 
 3: [91807000000, 50503000000, 142310000000, 248028000000], 
 4: [0, 45174000000, 45898000000, -584000000, 90488000000], 
 5: [338516000000]}
        
dict2 = 
{0: [48844000000, 51713000000, 22926000000, 4106000000, 22878000000, 12352000000], 
1: [], 
2: [46236000000, 37720000000, 5522000000, 5980000000, 10260000000], 
3: [], 
4: [45174000000, 45898000000, -584000000], 
5: []}
```

I want to create a third dictionary with the same general structure as dict1 but for every Key in dict1 that equals the Key in dict2 compare the values. And if the values match then true else false.
Basically I want compare every key:value pair between the 2 dictionaries but get the matching elements within the value in a format that matches dict1.

```
dictionary 3 should look like:
dict3 = 
{0: [true, true, true, true, true, true, false], 
 1: [false, false, false, false, false], 
 2: [true, true, true, false, true, true, false], 
 3: [false, false, false, false], 
 4: [false, true, true, true, true], 
 5: [true]}
```

is there a way to do this?

I ended up finding a solution as follows. Not pretty but I'm a noob and all I need is for it to work.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dict1 ={0: [48844000000, 51713000000, 22926000000, 4106000000, 22878000000, 12352000000, 162819000000], 1: [105341000000, 37378000000, 32978000000, 175697000000, 338516000000], 2: [46236000000, 37720000000, 5522000000, 6000000000, 5980000000, 10260000000, 105718000000], 3: [91807000000, 50503000000, 142310000000, 248028000000], 4: [0, 45174000000, 45898000000, -584000000, 90488000000], 5: [338516000000]}
        
dict2 = {0: [48844000000, 51713000000, 22926000000, 4106000000, 22878000000, 12352000000], 1: [], 2: [46236000000, 37720000000, 5522000000, 5980000000, 10260000000], 3: [], 4: [45174000000, 45898000000, -584000000], 5: []}

#create a DF for dict1 
df1 = df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1,orient='index') 

#create a DF for dict2
df2 = df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2,orient='index') 

#modify df2  
df2 = df2.values.tolist()                   #df2 to a list
df2 = itertools.chain(*df2)                 #Flatten that list      
df2 = [x for x in df2 if str(x) != 'nan']   #take out all nan values from the list
df3 = df1.isin(df2).astype(int)             #find any values in common between df1 and df2

df4 =df3[df1.isnull()].fillna(3).replace(0, np.NaN)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3.values.ravel(), columns=['prediction'])  #flatten the dataframe to a single column
df4 = pd.DataFrame(df4.values.ravel(), columns=['template'])    #flatten the dataframe to a single column    

df= pd.concat([df3,df4], axis=1, join='inner').dropna() 
df= df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(df['prediction'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, as I understood, you want to loop into your dictionnary and see if each value correspond with those of the other. You may first try by yourself. But here are some hints:

-A dictionnary have different keys, each value being a list, you may use two `for`loops

-I have written a short programm that answers your question. I would suggest you to create your dict three at the beggining just like this:

```
dict3 = {
    0: [],
    1: [],
    2: [],
    3: [],
    4: [],
    5: [],
}
```

To therefore loop into it and do the operations you want (as you are dealing with lists, you should consider using `append()`
-Your two dictionnaries don't have the same shape, so you may handle the cases were there is no value to compare with (with a `try...except...else` statement for example)

Finally, I just wanted to specify that creating dictionnaries like you did (by skipping a line) would give you a syntax error. So you may create them just like that:

```
dict2 = {
0: [48844000000, 51713000000, 22926000000, 4106000000, 22878000000, 12352000000], 
1: [], 
2: [46236000000, 37720000000, 5522000000, 5980000000, 10260000000], 
3: [], 
4: [45174000000, 45898000000, -584000000], 
5: []
}
```

Hoping it was helpfull, practice and feel free to ask if you have any question

Comment: thank you for the feed back. I ended up going a different route by using pandas since this is part of larger program that will need to be in a column format anyway. It isnt pretty but it works! I updated my question with my code. Thank you again!